# Mac linking dynamic library (boost -image not found)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

Im developing C++ application using xcode. And i built boost C++ successfully. overcome the Error image not found. I have first verified my dynamic libraries not having the path where these are located in.(i used otool -L) in oder to overcome it i followed [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902420/how-can-i-get-xcode-to-link-and-debug-an-app-with-boost-filesystem) Please find below the steps i used

**fyp** is my xcode project executable (exec)

1. First i gave path to libboost_filesystem.dylib to do that i used

   **install_name_tool -change libboost_filesystem.dylib /usr/local/lib/a/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib fyp**
2. I varified it by using

**otool -L fyp | grep libboost_filesystem.dylib**

```
**out put**-/usr/local/lib/a/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

3. And i link libboost_system.dylib into libboost_filesystem.dylib to do that i used

   **install_name_tool -change libboost_system.dylib /usr/local/lib/a/lib/libboost_system.dylib /usr/local/lib/a/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib**
4. I tried again otool -L fyp | grep libboost_filesystem.dylib

**libboost_filesystem.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)**

The Path i gave in step 1 is gone. Now im having the same error.which is

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/venushka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fyp-hdmbzawysyuciselqwbvjgjuhxbo/Build/Products/Debug/fyp
  Reason: image not found
```

how do i overocome this issue and work with this dynamic libararies. Any advance is appriated.

[image: Terminal]

In oder to do that i used bash script . But again i'm getting the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_filesystem.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/venushka/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/fyp-hdmbzawysyuciselqwbvjgjuhxbo/Build/Products/Debug/fyp
  Reason: image not found
```

The bash script

```
 install_name_tool -change libboost_filesystem.dylib $executable_path/libboost_filesystem.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_system.dylib $executable_path/libboost_system.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_thread.dylib $executable_path/libboost_thread.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_regex.dylib $executable_path/libboost_regex.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_log.dylib $executable_path/libboost_log.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_timer.dylib $executable_path/libboost_timer.dylib $FYP_PATH/fyp

    install_name_tool -change libboost_thread.dylib $executable_path/libboost_thread.dylib $executable_path/libboost_system.dylib

    install_name_tool -change libboost_system.dylib $executable_path/libboost_system.dylib $executable_path/libboost_filesystem.dylib
```

Comment: Run the program using `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=fyp ./the_program_you_want_to_run`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant can you please explain more. i think it might help others as well

Comment: what happens is you tell the linker to look for libraries in the local `fyp` directory. So the linker does, and it finds the library in the directory, links it against your executable, and writes its path into the executable. Now when you load the executable, the dynamic linker doesn't know that it has to look for libraries in the `fyp` directory, so it can't find the dylib, so it fails. Now if you tell it to look in `fyp`  by adjusting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, it will work.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  i cheked that please find my edited question.It also not working. any help is really appriated. thank you